# how to load more sector and call a function in the loaded sector

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, bios

I assembled the following code with

```
nasm -f bin option
```

and put it into floppy image and then run with virtualbox

my goal is to `call print_word`

but how can I `call print_word` here?

To learn how to call a function which is in extra sector,

I put `print_word` into second sector with intension.

Thanks in advance.

main.asm:

```
org 0x7c00
start:
    mov ax, 0x0206
    mov cx, 0x0002
    mov dx, 0x0000

    mov bx, 0x7e00
    push bx
    pop es

    mov bx, 0
.try_again:
    int 13h
    jc .try_again

    mov ax, 0xabcd
    push ax
    jmp 0x7e00


jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

more:
    %include "./common/print_word.asm"
```

print_word.asm:

```
;print_word(word)
print_word:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    push word [bp+4]
    call print_word_1

    push word [bp+4]
    call print_word_2
    push word [bp+4]
    call print_word_3
    push word [bp+4]
    call print_word_4
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret


print_word_1:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov byte al, [bp+4]
    shr al, 4
    cmp al, 0x0a
    jl .num
    sub al, 0x0a
    jmp .char
.num:
    add al, '0' 
    jmp .put
.char:
    add al, 'A'
    jmp .put
.put:
    int 10h
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret

print_word_2:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov byte al, [bp+4]
    shl al, 4
    shr al, 4
    cmp al, 0x0a
    jl .num
    sub al, 0x0a
    jmp .char
.num:
    add al, '0' 
    jmp .put
.char:
    add al, 'A'
    jmp .put
.put:
    int 10h
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret


print_word_3:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov byte al, [bp+5]
    shr al, 4
    cmp al, 0x0a
    jl .num
    sub al, 0x0a
    jmp .char
.num:
    add al, '0' 
    jmp .put
.char:
    add al, 'A'
    jmp .put
.put:
    int 10h
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret

print_word_4:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov byte al, [bp+5]
    shl al, 4
    shr al, 4
    cmp al, 0x0a
    jl .num
    sub al, 0x0a
    jmp .char
.num:
    add al, '0' 
    jmp .put
.char:
    add al, 'A'
    jmp .put
.put:
    int 10h
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular CALL instruction. Your assembler will assemble a CALL NEAR with a displacement rather an absolute address. Something like this:

```
mov ax,0xabcd
push ax
call print_word
add sp,2  ;to restore the stack

jmp $
```

Also, note that your `print_word routine`, when calling `print_word_1`, `print_word_2`, etc, doesn't restore the stack properly. Your calling convention requires the caller to remove the arguments it pushed on the stack, so after each `call print_word_N` instruction, you have to restore the stack, either by issuing an `add sp,2` instruction, or by popping the last stack element into an unused register. For example, like this:

As the value passed to the different print_word_N routines is always the same, and as your routines don't change the value of the parameter, you can optimize code size a litte by assuming the argument is already on the stack for the second and subsequent calls:

```
print_word:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    push word [bp+4]
    call print_word_1
    call print_word_2
    call print_word_3
    call print_word_4
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
```

BTW: Don't forget this is a little endian machine. You are converting to hex and printing the byte at `[ebp+4]`, then the byte at `[ebp+5]`. This will result in `CDAB` printed on screen. Two left-most digits of your hex number are located in the byte at `[ebp+5]` so you should print them first, then digits stored at byte `[ebp+4]`.

Ah! About loading sectors: your mistake is how you have considered the segment and offset of the block where the sector is loaded. You want to load the next sector at 0000:7E00, that is, next to the first 512 bytes of code loaded. Instead, you load it at 7E00:0000, which is not the same address at all.

The updated and fixed code is as follows (the part that loads the next sector):

```
org 0x7c00
start:
    mov ax, 0   ;segment is 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

.try_again:
    mov ax, 0x0201  ;load 1 sector
    mov cx, 0x0002  ;located at sector 2
    mov dx, 0x0000
    mov bx, 0x7e00  ;into 0000:7E00
    int 13h
    jnc .ok
.errorsector:
    mov ax,0   ;reset floppy controller ir error
    int 13h
    jmp .try_again

.ok:
    mov ax, 0xabcd
    push ax
    call print_word
    add sp,2

    jmp $
```

Comment: thanks very much for your replying, I tried call print_word, call 0x7e00, jmp print_word, call es:print_word. nothing print letter but shows blank screen or make errors. could you give me a further information?

Comment: it would be really nice to have short example. example of reading one more sector and call a function on loaded sector

Comment: About calling a function on a loaded sector, I've just provided that. The problem seems to be in the actual sector loading. If I move print_word routine to the first sector, it's working as expected.

Comment: I've found what's wrong with your sector loading code. Check updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much! after set es to 0 and set bx to 0x7e00, it works! but I still don't get why did you set ds to 0. plus one more, I tried bx to 0x8e00, 0x9e00 but it still works, I wonder why. thanks anyway